# Get output from command with Tcl expect

Tags: tcl, expect, gnu-screen

I've spent the better part of the day now searching everywhere for an answer, and nothing has worked so far.  What I'm trying to do is run an expect script that will attach to a GNU screen session, send it the command line arguments (a command), and output the result of that one command.  So far this is one of my scritps:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set timeout 3
#exp_internal 1

spawn screen -raAd call_sess
sleep 1

expect -re "\\\$" {
  send $argv
  send "\n"
  sleep 1
}

expect -re ".*" {
    set output $expect_out(0,string)
}

expect "\$" {
  send "\001"
  send "d"
}

expect eof {
  puts "OUTPUT---------------"
  puts $output
  puts "OUTPUT---------------"
}
```

And $expect_out(0,string) only matches a newline, even though .* should match everything since the last match.  If anyone could help me get this working that would be awesome, I'm about ready to give up and call it impossible.

EDIT:  Answered in the comments, but I should have specified that the command does get run in the screen, I just can't capture the output correctly.

EDIT2: Changed the script to spawn screen as suggested, thanks!

Comment: It's a guess: shouldn't you send '\r' after sending $argv?

Comment: '\n' works for sending a command, that much I know for sure.  Running 3.6.5-1-ARCH if that makes a difference.  The command gets run, I just can't capture the output correctly.

Comment: I don't know much about Expect, but can you work around by redirecting the output of that command to a temp file, then read off that file?

Comment: I thought about that, but that won't work in all cases.  I want this to be a dumb wrapper, and work for any command.

Answer (score 2):

The easy part of the answer is that `.*` is matching the empty string, so that's going into `expect_out`.

The hard part is that screen will give you the whole screen - including any previous commands -, so just finding the output of the command you sent might be a little difficult.

Comment: But shouldn't it be greedy?  Or are you saying `.*` will only ever match the empty string?  And if so, how would you match more than that?

Comment: It is a greedy match only against whatever happens to be in the buffer at that time, and since it will always match something it's not going to force expect to read anything more from the spawned process.  It's far more reliable to expect whatever comes at the end of the command (such as the next prompt), so you know when it's complete.  That way expect will keep reading from the spawned process.

Comment: also, why are you spawning a shell and then running screen, rather than simply spawning screen?

Comment: I changed up the script to spawn screen, didn't realize you could do that (not sure why).